# How to fix link redirect to index page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

First of all if someone has better idea for title please do it. So, I have a task  and I don't know how to fix it. It goes like this: I have a plain php mobile website, with a search form. After I select the search criteria return some links in this form:

```
<?= ereg_replace("HPG",$alias,$row["HPG_PLAN_ID"])?>.html">
```

Link will send me to: www.blabla.com/HPG-3000-1.html   ($row["HPG_PLAN_ID"] = -3000-1). If I go to that link it just render the index page(link remains the same). 
Code is not made by me ofcourse, so is hard to understand how it goes.

plan_detail.php file doesn't exist.(this might be the problem?)

Here are the `.htaccess` rules (copied from [this JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qmtbmax/)):

```
#RewriteEngine on 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ [NC] 
##RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

## REDIRECTS FOR ALL PLANS - TO DIRECTORIES
##===============================

##RewriteRule ^-(.*)/$  /m/plan_detail.php?planid=HPG-$1

## REDIRECTS FOR ALL PLANS - TO STATIC HTML PAGE
##===============================

#RewriteRule ^-(.*)\.html$  plan_detail.php?planid=HPG-$1

#RewriteRule ^HPG-(.*)\.html$  plan_detail.php?planid=HPG-$1
```

I know it might be more than a few ways to resolve this. But a little help is highly needed, I think the problem is simple but I can't see it.

Thanks!

Comment: The `htaccess` file that you've posted seems to have every line commented out. I don't know if that's the problem but if that's a copy of your actual file it probably is. Are you saying that navigating to _blabla.com/HPG-3000-1.html_ simply shows the exact contents of _blabla.com/index.php_?

Comment: If that `htaccess` file is active then the issue is, as you've mentioned, that the `plan_detail.php` file doesn't exist and you're trying to redirect to it.

Comment: Could you detail what you're actually trying to achieve with this whole thing? It seems a very complicated way to go about any sort of redirect or URL prettifying.

Comment: hmmm silly me. .htaccess is not active(all commented). What I am trying to achive is to get that produc description(search form-->click blabla.com/HPG-3000-1.html  to go to product page---> product page(but it goes me to index page)

Comment: hmmmm if I make another php file, I can't go into that. will redirect me to index.

Comment: Easiest way to debug at present, just rename your `.htaccess` file (add `.bak` or something) and that will remove any redirection errors. Can you not just link the product to (e.g.) `product.php?id=3000-1` ?